# How does Rc::clone(&pointer) increment reference count?

Tags: rust

I can't see how the following code is supposed to be implemented:

```
let a = Rc::new(5);
let b = Rc::clone(&a);
let c = Rc::clone(&a);
```

`Rc::clone` takes an immutable reference to `a`, yet somehow manages to increment its reference count (which would require a mutable reference?).

I tried inspecting the source code of `Rc` ([see here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/eceec57f72150dd548e05025a05a93381da41385/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L1129)) but couldn't yet understand it with my currently limited knowledge.

Is this working because it's using `unsafe` code under the hood, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood, `Rc` uses `Cell`, which enables interior mutability:

```rust
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}
```

And eventually, all roads lead to [`Cell::replace`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/cell.rs#L429). Inevitably it has a unsafe block:

```rust
mem::replace(unsafe { &mut *self.value.get() }, val)
```

So yes, your intuition was right!

Answer (score 4):

Internally, the [reference counter](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/eceec57f72150dd548e05025a05a93381da41385/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L260) is implemented with a [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), which is made precisely to *"enables mutation inside an immutable struct"*. And you are right, `Cell` [uses `unsafe` to allow mutation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/cell.rs.html#430).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer! Too bad I can't accept 2 answers at the same time